# Java ResourceBundle locale() NULL exception

Tags: java, resourcebundle

I am trying to set locale dynamically in java ResourceBundle like:
`ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle(pathAndFilename,locale());`

I tried to cover all possibilities in my following code to detect browser language and set it and if not exist in bundles then en_US could be used as default language:

```
    private Locale setLanguage(){
        Locale locale = request.getLocale();
                if (locale.getLanguage().equals("ar")){             
                    locale = new Locale("ar", "AE");                    
                }
                else if (locale.getLanguage().equals("fa")){                    
                    locale = new Locale("fa", "IR");
                }
                else if (locale.getLanguage().equals("en")){                    
                    locale = new Locale("en", "US");
                }
                else{
                    locale = new Locale("en", "US");
                }
    return locale;
    }

    private Locale locale(){
        Locale locale=null;     
            if(country == null){
                locale = setLanguage();                 
            }else{          
                locale = new Locale(language, country);
            }
    return locale;
    }
```

but method locale() is returning **null_NULL**
Please advise where I am making mistake?

I searched a lot but unable to find my mistake

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have added more information to the question. Please let me know if its still not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you are getting "null" as a value in following method. So change it as `if(country == null || country.equals("null")){`:

```
private Locale locale(){
    Locale locale=null;     
        if(country == null || country.equals("null")){
            locale = setLanguage();                 
        }else{          
            locale = new Locale(language, country);
        }
return locale;
}
```

Let me know if you still face problem

Comment: You save my day! I was sorting this problem for the last 3 hours but was not able to understand this point. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try changing code in your setLanguage() method:
taken from javaDoc of Locale class

> ISO 639 is not a stable standard— some languages' codes have changed. Locale's constructor recognizes both the new and the old codes for the languages whose codes have changed, but this function always returns the old code. If you want to check for a specific language whose code has changed, don't do:

```
if (locale.getLanguage().equals("he")) // BAD!
    ...
```

Instead, do

```
if (locale.getLanguage().equals(new Locale("he").getLanguage()))
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for optimizing my code and your advise but how its help me to control null_NULL?

Comment: I was just hoping that value might come from mentioned method :/ sorry it did not help.